# Automating windows mobile apps using winium and selenium using java

Tags: java, maven, selenium, windows-10-mobile

I have already created a maven project for test automating windows desktop applications with the help of winium in java. Now I have to develop a project for test automating windows mobile apps in java. I have searched a lot for the implementation but I couldn't get any example in java. Could you please help me to build this project in java?

Answer (score 0):

If the apps are Universal Windows Platform applications, you can go try appium.

http://appium.io/

Comment: I have already used appium for both android and ios phone applications testing... But can we have options available for windows phone app testing in appium using java?

Comment: http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/windows/ , here we can see that it is only for desktop applications

Comment: Yes. It does not support native windows apps but what i mentioned is it also supports Universal Windows Platform apps.

Comment: Okey... For native apps what we can use?